# could not connect to a website ? what does it mean?

Tags: google-chrome, http, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, pega

Could not connect to academy.pega.com

**Details:**

Peer disconnected after first handshake message: `Possibly SSL/TLS Protocol level is too low or unsupported on the server`

**Options:**

Pressing the button allows you to go to the previous page.

```
You can try to reload the page or check if the URL is correct.
```

**P.s:**
I am trying to connect to `pdn.pega.com` and `academy.pega.com`. I tried with all the browsers it is showing the same error.I feel that it is not going into secure even though I'mm using https?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how helpful it is but I can confirm that I can access both of those sites over a secure SSL connection.  I confirmed on multiple browsers as well.[image: Pega Academy website].

Comment: how to connect those sites through a secure SSL connection.?

Comment: @tejaswinisana If you are connected through a network then please seek help from your network team.